# Find if twig array is empty of non-protected values

Tags: php, twig

Given an a php array in a twig template:

```
object(Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute)#1208 (1) {
    ["storage":protected]=> array(0) { }
}
```

How do I check if there are no non-protected elements in the array? The idea is that I can only operate on non-protected values, so I can pretend the array is empty if only protected values are present.

So far, my check is as follows:

```
{% if attributes is defined and attributes is not empty %}
    <div{{ attributes }}>
      {{ content }}
    </div>
{% else %}
    {{ content }}
{% endif %}
```

In its current form, this displays `<div>[Content]</div>`. Instead, I'd like to see: `[Content]`

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If this is in Drupal 8, you can pass the attributes value through render to find out, like this:

```
{% if attributes|render %}
  <div{{ attributes }}>
    {{ content }}
  </div>
{% else %}
  {{ content }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Extend twig

   ```
   <?php
      $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
      $twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('accessible_properties', 'get_object_vars'));
   ```
2. Use it inside template

   ```
   {% set public_attributes = attributes is defined ? (attributes|accessible_properties) : [] %}
   {% if public_attributes is not empty %}
       ...
   {% else %}
       ...
   {% endif %}
   ```